# Gastric and intestinal gas exchange

Tags: digestive-system, breathing, gastroenterology

A very long time ago, I happened across research into using an oxygenated liquid in the stomach and or intestinal  cavity.  I wondered what further results came about of that research, and am having difficulty finding anything on it.   Is anyone aware of it and it and or  can point me to articles and or research papers done?

Answer (score 2):

Intestinal gas consists of ingested air and gas formed during digestion. Stomach gas consists of  15% oxygen and 7% carbon dioxide approximately; the remaining is nitrogen.

The air that we breathe contains about 21% oxygen; thus some of the swallowed oxygen is absorbed through the blood capillaries present in stomach. Carbon dioxide is synthesized by digesting food using gastric juices. Nitrogen is not absorbed.

The small intestine absorbs some amount of carbon dioxide and oxygen. And the remaining gas is passed further to the large intestine. In the large intestine,  most of the oxygen is removed and carbon dioxide is increased. New gases are produced mainly hydrogen because of bacterial fermentation. And these gases are absorbed by blood and later released via lungs.

Check out following links:

https://katesalevelbiology.wordpress.com/2017/02/14/human-gas-exchange-the-digestive-system-and-breathing/

https://www.gastrojournal.org/article/S0016-5085(19)33654-6/pdf

https://journals.physiology.org/doi/abs/10.1152/ajplegacy.1926.76.1.92

https://nyaspubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/j.1749-6632.1968.tb19024.x

Comment: Kindly let me know, if these links are useful. I can share whole research articles as some of these links need subscription.

Answer (score 0):

Asking the question here inspired new terms for me to search and I belive I found information on the original article I had happened across where researchers tried to oxygenate pigs by perfusing the abdominal cavity with oxygenated perfluorocarbons.
[Penn researchers use the abdomen to deliver oxygen to assist ailing lungs](https://www.eurekalert.org/pub_releases/2006-08/uops-pru080706.php)

Link to a research paper.

[Peritoneal Perfusion With Oxygenated Perfluorocarbon Augments Systemic Oxygenation](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/16899838/)