# Does all CO2 from the blood leave the body through the respiratory system?

Tags: human-biology, physiology, human-physiology, homeostasis, human

I know that the primary way that CO2 leaves a healthy human’s body from the blood is by diffusing into the lungs during gas exchange and then being exhaled. Is there any other way in which CO2 from the blood leaves the body? Since CO2 is a gas, it only leaves the body when gas is expelled. As far as I know, gases are only stored in the lungs, stomach, and intestines, and they can only expelled by breathing, burping, and farting. Is the CO2 released during burps and farts from the blood? Is there any other way that I didn't account for by which CO2 leaves the body?

[This link](https://www.sciencefocus.com/planet-earth/how-much-does-human-breathing-contribute-to-climate-change/) states that an average person exhales about 500 liters of carbon dioxide every day. How do the numbers from burps and farts compare to that?

This might be useful in identifying hypercapnia or hypocapnia unrelated to respiratory function.

Edit: Bicarbonate is a form of carbon dioxide, and it is excreted in urine.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve/what's the significance of the question? Why would it matter if CO2 is lost some way besides exhalation?

Comment: I just want to know.

Comment: The [help] says "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face". We usually interpret that fairly broadly, but there really should be *some* motivation for a question besides mere trivia.

Comment: Here's a situation where that might matter: A doctor wants to measure rates of CO2 production in the body to very high accuracy by measuring average CO2 expulsion over a day by putting sensors on the patient's body, but if he didn't account for all the places in the body where CO2 is expelled, he'd underestimate the CO2 production rate.

Comment: Great, that seems like a good motivation to me. Ideally you could edit that into the original question, as it will help frame answers.

Comment: humans do uptake tiny amounts of oxygen through skin so it should be worth looking to see if they do the same with co2. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2290093/

Comment: It would seem (to me) only to be important if a person had hypercarbia unrelated to pulmonary function. Air in the upper GI tract is usually swallowed air; air in the lower GI tract is both swallowed air and gasses produced by bacterial fermentation of contents, so don't really represent CO2 produced by the body anyway.

Comment: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/94330/gastric-and-intestinal-gas-exchange might help.

Comment: Maybe helpful, maybe not. The only current source is the first, and it doesn't discuss gas in the GI tract at all. The others are ancient (from a scientific viewpoint). Some physiological processes may take millions of years to change, but knowledge about the processes advances quickly. PS: Is bicarb excretion in the urine significant? (Among other things, the kidney's job is to conserve bicarb.)